# How to deal with negating more than 1 and (∧)?

Tags: logic

If I have a logic statement with more than 1 and that is not explicitly grouped together, like here:
**(P(w, f ) ∧ Q(f, a) ∧ C(w,a))**
how should I go about trying to negate this whole statement?

Comment: Conjunction is associative: $(P\wedge Q)\wedge R\equiv P\wedge(Q\wedge R)$. So you can group it any way you want and negate; or prove the generalization of De Morgan’s law for an arbitrary conjunction and an arbitrary disjunction.

Comment: I see, that makes a lot of sense and I can see how the negation could be distributed that way. Thank you!